# Error loading psycopg2 module when installed from a 'wheel'

Tags: pip, docker, psycopg2, python-wheel

I am trying to install some python requirements from a local package directory containing [wheel](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip_wheel.html) archives. I am installing the requirements inside a Docker container.

The steps I'm following are:

```sh
$ pip install wheel
# wheel runs, outputs .whl files to wheelhouse directory
$ pip wheel --wheel-dir wheelhouse -r requirements.txt
```

Then, inside my `Dockerfile`:

```sh
ADD requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
ADD wheelhouse /tmp/wheelhouse
# install requirements. Leave file in /tmp for now - may be useful.
RUN pip install --use-wheel --no-index --find-link /tmp/wheelhouse/ -r /tmp/requirements.txt
```

This works - and all the requirements are installed correctly:

```sh
# 'app' is the name of my built docker image
$ docker run app pip list
...
psycopg2 (2.5.1)
...
```

However, if I actually try running something inside the container that **uses** `psycopg2`, then I get the following:

```sh
Error loading psycopg2 module: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_AsUTF8String
```

I presume that this is something to do with the way in which the wheels were built - I ran `pip wheel` on the container host machine (Ubuntu 12.04).

How can I fix this - using wheels significantly reduces the time taken to build the container image, so I don't want to revert to installing packages if I can help it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what a wheel or a docker is, but your error comes from a mismatch between the Python used to build the module and the one that is trying to run it.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, psycopg2 can be rather finicky when installing/building from source, so am not surprised that it doesn't package into a wheel. However, could you simply wheel everything apart from psycopg2? Still would save you a heap of time.

Comment: Thanks Steve - and yes, you're probably right, however am not going to give you the prize just yet - someone may come up with an answer... :-)